# Dynamic range for a table specific column

Tags: excel, listobject, vba

I have a table that contains 3 columns. In the thirs column, when I click on it I want a calendar to pop out and slect a date. This is working perfectly but I have to manually set my range in the coding below. I would like the 3rd column("C") to have a dynamic range for everytime I add a line in my table of data. (Name of table = "Table1")

Thanks in advance,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1:C10")) Is Nothing Then UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to read up on how to reference parts of a table.

Answer (score 1):

To trigger your UserForm1 on cell selection that includes the third column of data in your table (not to include the table header), try,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, listobjects("table1").DataBodyRange.Columns(3)) Is Nothing Then UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

If you want the cell selection trigger to include the header, simply change DataBodyRange to Range.